# WUBI hangs while "Almost finished copying files"

Tags: wubi

WUBI hangs while "Almost finished copying files" on both 12.04 and 12.10.
I'm using Dell Latitude E5410 with i3Core processor and 8MB of Ram. Operating system is Win7Pro.
THANX

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. i had allocated 8GB for ubuntu installation and my installation disk was formatted as NTFS.

I allocated 12GB and changed my format to FAT32, then i managed to install my ubuntu. As i have done the changes at the same time, i am not sure which change did the trick. I think it had something to do with the disk allocation size.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Wubi runs even if disk is NTFS. It must be the disk size. 15GB is expected for good installation.

Comment: That can't be it. I'm having the same problem while trying to install ubuntu in a 42GB partition.

Comment: @f03lipe 30Gb is the max. WUBI can have ;)